# Can I say "which I interpret that ..."?

Tags: word-usage

I am not sure if I can use the combination "which I interpret that" in this example:

> The font used is old fashioned **which I interpret that the text** was printed before 1750.

Comment: You can say: *The font used is old fashioned, by   which I interpret that the text was printed before 1750.*  Or use *on account of which* instead of *by which*.

Comment: Or "*from which I conclude that*", or "*which leads me to conclude that*".  We just don't really use *interpret* the way you're using in in that sentence.